# is there a way to list numbers from smallest to largest python using def? not using python built in functions

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to create function which will show numbers from smallest to largest, using def, not by python built in function like sort(), 
how can i do this ?

i have tried to search in google to fix this problem

```
# Data structures --> arrays

print('Welcome')
number = []
nums_len = int(input('Enter how many numbers: '))

def enter_nums():
    for nums in range(nums_len):
        num = int(input('Enter numbers: '))
        number.append(num)
enter_nums()

# O(N) search running speed
maximum = number[0]
minimum = number[0]

for nums in number:
    if nums > maximum:
        maximum = nums
print(maximum, 'is a max number')
for nums in number:
    if nums < minimum:
        minimum = nums
print(minimum, 'is a min number')
```

i already set up application which shows min and max numbers from the list, but i need it to show me numbers from smallest to largest

Comment: Is this a quiz or homework problem?

Comment: homework problem

Comment: Since this is a homework problem, I'd strongly suggest checking your school's academic honesty policy before submitting an answer from stack overflow. It sounds as if your instructors would like you to implement a sort function, or come up with a creative way to print an unordered list in order. Try reading through some of the [wikipedia pages on sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting) for inspiration on choosing a sort algorithm and implementing it. You could come up with another solution such as repeatedly traversing your list of numbers and printing then removing the minimum, or rep

Comment: Suggest you try implementing bubble sort, it's pretty quick and easy.  Hint: Python has a built in swap function. a = [1,2,3], then you can say a[0],a[1] = a[1],a[0] and your list is now a = [2, 1, 3].  Of course you only want to do that if a[0] > a[1]...

Answer (score -1):

They're asking you to implement sort itself in some manner. Here's one of the simpler sort algorithms, insertion sort. Note it uses an internal helper function:

```py
def sort_insertion(numbers):
    def insert(numbers, position, value):
        i = position - 1
        while i >= 0 and numbers[i] > value:
            numbers[i + 1] = numbers[i]
            i = i - 1
        numbers[i + 1] = value

    for x in range(1, len(numbers))
        insert(numbers, x, numbers[x])
    return numbers
```

Be sure to walk through these examples and see how each value changes as the algorithm cycles.
*PS My resource for algorithms is Algorithms in a Nutshell, A Practical Guide, Heineman, Pollice & Selkow, O'Reilly. It's got all the basics and some complex ones, in pseudocode or C, C++, Java, Python. Cheaper than most textbooks.
**PPS copying and pasting code will not help you pass exams!